# I got an other issue why is it returning incorrect in both buttons if i click on them?

Tags: java, android

I got an other issue why is it returning incorrect in both buttons if i click on them? Can someone test and tell me why it does that..i need help

http://pastebin.com/KZWBpwx5

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. In this case, it would include the `com.example.android.rareenglishwords.MainActivity` implementation.

Comment: `access to class not allowed`... meaning it is likely not defined as `public class`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have edited your post and asked another question. How lovely.
So from your code it's clear that You show toast labeled as correct for noButton and toast labeled as incorrect for yesButton. Switch toast strings........

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your com.example.android.rareenglishwords.MainActivity class is declared as public in MainActivity.java.
as in

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity //or AppCompat activity... whatever activity you use
```

You haven't provided a code snippet, so hard to see. But this error is most likely to be a result of Instrumentation not being able to access a class, because class is not declared as public

Comment: It will not let me paste it,may i send you it by email or some other way,please?

Comment: Just make sure your activity class is public. that should solve it. As I mentioned.

Comment: If you could check out how come I got that error I would be double grateful for you help

Comment: You got that error because for some reason when you first ran your app your activity was not a public class. Android Instrumentation cannot run activity if in your application it's not declared as public. Activity must always be public.

Comment: I see now you have edited your question and added a completely different question instead. In general you probably should not do that. But I added another answer for you.